# Have auto-pst-pdf and pstool merged?

Tags: pdftex, pstricks, psfrag, auto-pst-pdf, pstool

`auto-pst-pdf` can handle `pstricks` and `psfrag` in addition to `.eps` files when run with pdflatex. It is however slow since in each run it processes all files, even those that have been processes before and have not changed since since last process. `pstool` is faster since is avoids reprocessing, however it cannot handle `pstricks` code. I was wondering if any attempt has been put to merge the packages (or simply prevent `auto-pst-pdf` from reprocessing)?